# Calling Javascript code in ASP (Visual Basic)

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, vbscript

I need to work with an ASP page coded in Visual Basic

I was wondering how I could create an error popup with the content:

```
alert("No such entry exists")
```

in visual basic. Is there a way to embed javascript code in visual basic or do error pop-ups in visual basic itself?

Comment: Do you mean VB in Classic ASP? if not, whats hosting the VB?

Comment: So is this an HTML page viewed in Internet Explorer, with VB code **in** the page as script?

Comment: The VB code is in <%...%>. It's a collection of asp files with some html and vb content.

Answer (score 2):

A simple Response.Write should work. Try this:

```
<% Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert('No such entry exists');</script>") %>
```

It's been way too long since I've done Classic ASP, so you may need to verify that "" is the right way to escape quotes in a VBscript string.

Comment: I should clarify. The Visual Basic is in an asp page already enclosed <%...%>, so I can't put a different set of tags inside it.

Comment: If you're already inside code, just leave off the <% %> in my answer above. It should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

An asp page is just a type of html page. Anything you could put in plain html, such as a script block, can also be put in an asp page. Obviously, though, if it's not server-side script, then it shouldn't go inside the `<% %>` markers.

```
 <%Option Explicit%>
 <!DOCTYPE ... >
 <html>
 <head>
 --html header stuff goes here, like css declarations--
 <script type...>
 --javascripty (client-side) things go here--
 </script>
 <%
 --vbscript (server-side) stuff goes here, or you can change your
 server settings to use javascript instead--
 %>
 </head>
 <body>
 --more combinations of straight html markup, 
 client-side scripting enclosed in <script> tags, and 
 server-side code enclosed in <% %>--
 </body>
 </html>
```

Note that you want to minimize the dropping in and out of server-side script, but the point is that you can have as many code blocks as you need.